# PHPMailer Undefined Type (Tried Composer also)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I don't know why I am getting this 'PHPMailer Undefined Type' error. Firstly I tried directly download zip and copy the code from github, same problem came then I downloaded composer that I didn't want to but downloaded still it's showing the same error.

Please can I get any thought on it ?? (Screenshot below)

[error with composer img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ctIt.png)

[same error without composer img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZT8r.png)

[Directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeJ6Q.png)

here is the code

session_start();

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 
 
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php'; 
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php'; 
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php'; 
 
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);   // error coming here
 
$mail->isSMTP();                      // Set mailer to use SMTP 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;               // Enable SMTP authentication 
$mail->Username = 'user@gmail.com';   // SMTP username 
$mail->Password = 'gmail_password';   // SMTP password 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted 
$mail->Port = 587;                    // TCP port to connect to 
 
// Sender info
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try putting the `require` statements above the `use` statements?

Comment: Hi ! yes, I tried but the problem was same, I have commented below how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use composer, only autoload is necessary (it does all the 'require' work)

```
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php'
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php'; < -- this is no longer used
```

Comment: Hi Isaac ! thanks for the answer. I tried it but the problem was same. Now I found the solution. The problem was in Intelephense, when I disabled it and enabled the builtin php intellisense in visual studio, the error was gone and the application was working fine. Only Intelephense was showing this as error, I don't know why but now I uninstalled Intelephense.